# Proof of Lemma 1 paper " Provably Secure Partially Blind Signatures Masayuki ABE and Tatsuaki OKAMOTO"

Tags: hash, signature

I'm troubled by a system of equations presented in the paper "Provably Secure Partially Blind Signatures" Masayuki ABE and Tatsuaki OKAMOTO.

[image: Proof part 1]

[image: proof part 2]

In  lemma 1  the authors define $t_2=w_j-c_i$ however  $c_i$  following the signature protocol creates a feed back loop as $t_2$ is defined and used as input in a secure hash function.
[image: Signature protocol]

Why is it true that the equations always have a solution?

Comment: https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2000/18800272/18800272.pdf